# Animation turns into Action of a body part

Tags: animation, actions

When I am animating a character I often have the problem that the animation suddenly disappears or is reduced to only one frame of the original animation. If I then go through my other animations (I am animating a game character) I find that the animation that disappeared or changed turned into an action of another body part. Is there any way to transform the action back into the animation? I often don't notice that the animation turns into an action and I have to redo the whole animation.

I really don't have a clue why this problem occurs but I had it probably 10 times now so I would really appreciate your help! :-)

Edit:
I tried to recreate it in Photoshop, sorry that it is so rough! But this is kind of what it looks like.
[image]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean, animation and action are the same thing, if you keyframe an object in the Timeline, you can open the Dope Sheet/Action Editor and you'll see that it's an action

Comment: I added an image where I tried to recreate the problem maybe you can see this way what's going on?

Comment: is your eye a separate object? and is it parented to a bone? maybe share a very simple example: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: the problem is that my model is under nda :( the eyes, eyelids and the body are seperate objects but they are all parented to the same rig (but different bones)

Comment: maybe you can remove or alter some elements to only keep something very simple that would help to understand the problem

Comment: It's very hard to understand your problem, have you correctly understood how the Dope Sheet and Nonlinear Animation Editor work? And how to switch between actions? That in the same armature action you can mix keyframes for the bones and for the armature object itself, etc? It looks like it's a basic misunderstanding about basics, no?

Comment: Yeah I think that it is probably a basic misunderstanding but I'm not sure how to look for these basics :/ I watched almost every video about the nonlinear animation editor and I'm pretty sure that I understand the dope sheet. Can you recommend a youtube channel or a blog or something similar that explains actions in depth?

Comment: it would be easy if you reproduce your problem with a very simple example, we would understand quickly. For the channels I like to cite Grant Abbitt but I don't know if he has made a lot of tutos on animations, you should easily find some if you type "dope sheet beginner blender" etc

Comment: haha i think if i could reproduce the problem I would understand what's going on :D but thank you! If it happens again I will message you maybe then we can find a solution! Thanks a lot for trying to help :)